# Umbraco: Unable to get RelatedLinks property value in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have a RelatedLinks property in one of my pages that I need to get the links/PageIds out from in the code behind of my macro-user control.

I can get the property like this

```
var current = Node.GetCurrent();
Response.Write("Output: " + current.GetProperty("RelatedLinks").Value);
```

But the output is empty. When I debug I can see that the Value includes some list content (like  tags and such) some somehow nothing is printed.

My question is how I can get the value from this property into something like a collection of hyperlink objects.

I'm new to Umbraco and I's possible that I'm missing something essential here. Getting the content of other property types (like the Content Picker)  works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
        Document doc = new Document(Node.GetCurrent().Id);
        umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property relatedLinks = doc.getProperty("RelatedLinks");
        XmlNode relatedLinksAsXml = relatedLinks.ToXml(new XmlDocument());
```

However it says that the Document class is obsolete and wants me to use Umbraco.Core.Models.Content instead. But this is MVC right? I'm trying to use webforms. Tried using the Node class as described in this thread but the Property object I got returned was of the wrong type and couldn't be converted to XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple solution in Umbraco 7.+

```
Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<Umbraco.Web.Models.RelatedLinks>("relatedArticles");
```

this simply convert data to static type that is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

What data type is your related links set to, assuming its a content picker where you are getting the id of the related page you could first create a node form your current page's id then try and get the value from that node e.g.

```
var current = Node.GetCurrent();
var currentPage = Model.NodeById(current.Id);
var relatedLinks = currentPage.RelatedLinks; 
or
var relatedLinks = GetProperty("RelatedLinks").Value;
```

when you debug you should be able to see all the properties of currentpage and check your alias as well to make sure its right (generally aliases dont start with a capital by default).

Comment: I'm using the RelatedLinks datatype in Umbraco where you can select several links. They seem to be stored in in XML-format, so that could be the reason I can't get the values like other properties such as from the Content Picker datatype. I tried the Model.NodeById() example you posted but it didn't work, probably since I'm using webforms user controls instead of MVC. So I guess I need to retrieve the property data in XML-format somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().GetProperty("RelatedLinks")